# AS3: Applying filters to BitmapData instead of the Bitmap?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, bitmap

I have a large background `Bitmap` image that I blur with a tween, and it doesn't go very smoothly on lower end computers. I've read that you can apply filters to the `BitmapData` instead. Would that have any effect on performance?

Comment: I doubt it since the bitmapdata is the content of the bitmap itself. Is this a scrolling background? Maybe only draw the visible part & blur that smaller segment. Look on google how to draw a segment of a larger bitmap. By offsetting where you draw each time it gives illusion of scrolling.

Comment: You should create a blurred version of the image outside of the application and use that. If it has to be created by the application during runtime, create a the blurred version in a regular movieclip, draw the clip to bitmap, and delete the movieclip. I can give you the code to convert movieclip to bitmap if you want.

Comment: Are you talking about the built-in filters in de Flash IDE? (blur, glow, drop-shadow, etc). Because those are very performance-heavy, to the point of being unusable. It might help to have a blurred image in the library and tick the 'cache as bitmap' option. You can indeed also use bitmapdata and filter that with an AS3 script, that should work better. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003706/applying-blur-filter-to-bitmapdata